# Can't handle data catched through modal.onDidDismiss() in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4, modalviewcontroller

I succeed to catch data (an object) from a modal page after it dismissed by using  `modal.onDidDismiss()` method but i can't handle and display it :

```
export class AbracadabrasyPage {

  private fastFood: any; 

  Menus: any[]; 
  Horaires: any[]; 
  Category: string; 


  constructor(public modalController: ModalController, private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet)
  { 
    console.log(this.fastFood); // it displays in the console : Undefined //

    this.Menus = this.fastFood.menus; 
    this.Horaires = this.fastFood.horaires; 
    this.Category = this.fastFood.cat
  };


  async onLOcate(){     
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: MapPage,
      swipeToClose: true,
      componentProps: {
        Lat: this.fastFood.latitude, 
        Lng: this.fastFood.longitude
      },
      presentingElement: this.routerOutlet.nativeEl 
    });
    modal.present(); 

    const { data } = await modal.onDidDismiss(); 
    if(data){
      this.fastFood = data;
      console.log(this.fastFood);
    };
  };
```

Comment: try ```await modal.present();``` since it returns a promise. Maybe the ```await modal.onDidDismiss();``` is resolving too early otherwise.

Comment: @capc0 thanks for your answer, but i have return with await modal.onDidDismiss(); the problem is that is resolving too late and this.fastFood can't be catched in the right time when the page is opened...

Comment: im not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Is your issue that the value is ```undefined``` in the constructor? If yes, that will always be the case be the constrcutor code will run first, no matter when the modal is opened or closed.